# add creation/modified time to python template in vim script

Tags: python, vim

I wrote a simple python template in ~/.vim/template/pythontmp.txt,

and use

```
$> autocmd bufnewfile *.py :0r ~/.vim/template/pythontmp.txt
```

to load the template when i create a new python script.

The problem is that i'd like to add creation time to the comment of the document.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use strftime function for this:

```
if exists('*strftime')
    au BufNewFile *.py :call append(0, '# Created: '.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %T %z'))
endif
```

According to the documentation, `strftime` is not present on some systems. See `man strftime` (if you are on *nix) for details of format.